# How to fix discord.py bot hosted by Heroku not going online?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to get my discord.py bot hosted for free, and I heard Heroku is a good option. My dyno is working perfectly, and it's switched on, but when I deploy, my bot does not go online. I have no errors, it says it's deployed, but my bot never goes online.

I have tried regenerating the bot token, and putting it in my Heroku app, but it still won't work.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import bot
import asyncio
import requests
import os

description = '''EchoBot by EchoNoahGaming'''
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-', description=description)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('------')

@bot.command()
async def announcement(ctx, *, args):
    """Announcement command!"""
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Announcement", description=args, color=0x7700aa)
    embed.set_footer(text="By EchoNoahGaming")
    await ctx.send("@everyone", embed=embed)

client.run(str(os.environ.get('BOT_TOKEN')))
```

That is the bot code.

I expected the bot to come online, because there were no errors, but it didn't, and it stayed offline.

The Procfile code is

```
worker: python3 bot.py
```

The requirements.txt content is

```
discord
asyncio
```

If you need anything else, tell me. The GitHub link is https://github.com/EchoNoahGaming/echobot/blob/master/ but i'll post any files on here so it's easier.

Comment: Hi, have you added the `BOT_TOKEN` environment variable into the "config var"s in Heroku settings?

Comment: Yes, I did. I tried changing it and regenerating my bot token but it won't work.

Comment: Hmm... `from discord.ext.commands import bot`. I've never seen that sort of line before. (Try removing it?) If you have the heroku cli installed, also try calling up the logs for tracebacks/errors `heroku logs -a <your-app-name>`, better that than trying to guess the error.

Comment: I think it's used to get discord.py,  but i'll try that.
EDIT: It did not work.

Comment: I am using GitHub, if that helps.

Comment: Semi-random guess: `bot.run` instead of `client.run`?

Comment: No errors, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Alright, so I tested your code on a repl.it with my own bot token. I replaced `client.run` with `bot.run` and my bot logged online. The code seems to be fine. (Given my suggestions above, please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55992696/edit) with what you currently have.) Since the issue doesn't seem to be with the code, can you share the contents of your Procfile and requirements.txt with us? Thanks.

Comment: sure! I'll edit it.

Comment: I edited it. Hope that helps.

Comment: Ah, that helps a bit. `asyncio` is part of the Python standard library, so it's not needed in requirements.txt. On the other hand, `requests` isn't part of the standard library, so it should be in requirements.txt.

Comment: It worked, thank you! I am really happy, because now I can host my thing. Thanks again!

Comment: That's great! I'll post a complete answer that summarises the above comments so that it may help future readers have an easier time.

Answer (score 2):

From the discussion in the comments, OP and I figured out what went wrong:

1. There is a typo on the last line: `client.run` should be `bot.run`
2. The requirements.txt file should be changed to

   ```
   discord.py
   requests
   ```

   This is because `requests` isn't part of the Python standard library whereas `asyncio` *is* part of the standard library.

Fixing the above seemed to have solve the issues.

---

An auxiliary code review would be to remove redundant lines, such as

```
from discord.ext.commands import bot
```

(which gets overwritten by `bot = Bot(...)` anyway).

The `asyncio` and `requests` modules weren't used in the code, but I'll give you the benefit of the doubt and assume you're planning on using them. If not, remove them from your code (and, if applicable, from requirements.txt). This saves time in building the bot.